# Spring MVC or WebFlow for this project

Tags: apache-flex, hibernate, spring, oracle10g

I have to create an application with 
Flex 4 with Swiz (MVC Framework) as the UI Layer, 
Spring (MVC or Web Flow) as the Business Layer,
Oracle 10g as Data layer,
Hibernate as ORM which will work with Oracle,
with Maven, with IBM Websphere and Tomcat.

I am trying to decide should I use Spring MVC (since it has to work with Swiz and Flex 4 which is MVC) or should I work with Spring Web Flow. Also any good examples on web with tutorials on this technology set.

I appreciate any help.

Thank you,
Sid

Comment: Spring Web Flow is not used for business logic, this is related to presentation... Clarify please, what are you going to implement with Spring MVC or Web Flow? What result of their using do you expect?

Comment: okay. That answers my question. Business loginc was supposed to be implemented for Spring (either MVC or Web Flow) since Web Flow is for presentation. Ill move forward with Spring MVC. I hope I have answered your question. Thank you Maxym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that WebFlow is primarily a page-flow framework, it's almost certainly inappropriate for your situation. Your Flex client will likely communicate via AJAX-style calls to the backend, and Spring MVC is the best choice for that.